# Code in java to set images for ImageView?

Tags: java, android

I'm kinda new to android development and having problem showing images from my drawable resource file with java code.
I simplified my original app to isolate the problem, so
now it is just a blank activity with one image view in the center.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView000"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public ImageView images;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    images = findViewById(R.id.imageView000);
    images.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageNameInDrawableFile);

}
```

}

There is no error in compilation.
But when I run this on the virtual device or my phone, the app crashes on start.
What's wrong?

Update: thank for the tips everyone. the problem was the directory of the image, it was "E:\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApplication\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24", just removed the "-v24" in directory shown after i drop myImage into drawable folder and it worked perfectly after.

Comment: *the app crashes on start. Whats wrong?* Why don't you share crash log with question

Comment: it just doesn't open. "app stopped working" message.

Answer (score 1):

Use `images.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageNameInDrawableFile)`;

setImageDrawable() requires a Drawable to be passed but you are passing an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use you're code in `onCreate`.

Cause `onStart` includes when the application is first created and when it is brought back on the screen without being terminated.

```
public ImageView images;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    images = findViewById(R.id.imageView000);
    images.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.your_image));
    //or
    images.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
}
```

Comment: I moved those codes to onCreate, its the same: "Unfortunately, app has stopped."

Comment: Context activity = null;
images.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.imageName)); //didnt work

Comment: images.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image); // didnt work.

Comment: @Datis you have to pass you're drawable make sure you have drawable present in drawable folder.

Comment: i found the problem, thanks for the tip mate. it was the directory of the image when i place it in drawable folder, "E:\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApplication\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24". just had to delete "-v24"... i was struggeling for 2 day!!!

Comment: @Datis if solution worked for you mark as answer and give upvote. Thanks

Comment: i gave upvote but it dosent show it because i have less than 15 reputation.